# Angular 5 не могу импортировать fabric

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular5, fabricjs

заинсталлено было так:
npm install @types/fabric --save

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { Canvas } from "fabric/fabric-impl";
import fabric = require("fabric/fabric-impl");

@Component({
  selector: "app-main-reconizer",
  templateUrl: "./main-reconizer.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./main-reconizer.component.css"]
})
export class MainReconizerComponent implements OnInit {

  private canvas: fabric.Canvas;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');  
    this.canvas.add(new fabric.IText('Hello Fabric!')); 

  }
}
```

Возникает ошибка:

```
./src/app/main-reconizer/main-reconizer.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fabric/fabric-impl' in 'D:\TestPrj\else development\Angular\PRJ\recognizerWEB\src\app\main-reconizer'
 @ ./src/app/main-reconizer/main-reconizer.component.ts 13:13-42
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:0 ./src/main.ts
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В файл .angular-cli.json в раздел scipts добавить строку с примерно таким содержанием

```
"scripts": [
    "../node_modules/you/path/to/file"
  ],
```

Укажи путь в node_modules к скрипту.
Если нужны css, то там же есть раздел css, аналогично подключаешь стили.

И заново запусти ng serve

А в файле своего компонента перед декоратором @Component добавь такую строку

```
declare const fabric: any;
```

И используй в коде fabric как бы использовал если бы писал на обычном JS.

Comment: А импорты удали